# is it possible to capture scrollstart on an element other than $(document) in Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, jquery-events

I'm trying to use the [Overthrow](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/) Plugin, which is a polyfill for overflow:auto on mobile devices. Sample [here](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/).

**My question:**
How can I detect scrollstart/scrollstop on a `div.element` that is scrollable? Is this possible at all, or do the scroll/scrollstart/scrollstop events only work on `$(document)`?

Specifically, if I have two panels on my page, which both are scrollable, is there any way to make this work:

```
 $(document).on('scrollstart','div:jqmData(panel="main"), div:jqmData(panel="menu")'), function() {
    console.log("scroll detected");
    });
```

**EDIT:**
My HTML looks like this:

```
<html class="ui-popover-mode">
// OR depending on screen size
<html class="ui-splitview-mode">
   // panel 1
   <div data-panel="main" class="ui-panel">
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="mainOne">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="mainTwo">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   // panel 2
   <div data-panel="menu" class="ui-panel">
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="menuOne">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="menuTwo">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   // panel 3
   <div data-panel="pop" class="ui-panel">
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="popOne">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
       <div data-role="page" class="ui-page" id="popTwo">
           <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

Screen Mode is set depending on screen size. In every panel there can be multiple pages, which each have a content section, which is scrollable using overthrow.

I want to bind to *scrollstart* in main and menu content section in **splitview-mode** AND main content sections in **popover-mode**.

Originally my selector tried to capture this and only attach to the relevant content elements:

```
$(document).on('scrollstart','.ui-splitview-mode div:jqmData(panel="main") .ui-content,  .ui-splitview-mode div:jqmData(panel="menu") .ui-content, .ui-popover-mode div:jqmData(panel="main") .ui-content, ', function() {
        // do sth
    });
```

Agreed this is complex and did not work. But it attached events only to the necessary elements. Now I'm doing like this:

```
$('.ui-content').on('scrollstart', function() {
        // check here if .ui-content is on the correct panel
    });
```

So I now have a lot of unnecessary bindings and only check if the binding is correct after the event is detected vs. the other way I would only attach the event to the required elements.

That's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly select the element and attach the scroll event. Simple example

```
$("#selector").on('scrollstart', function() {
    //...do stuff
});
```

Comment: strange. it works when I target the element directly, but not if I construct a more complex selector like $('.mode #selector')

Comment: @frequent, the event delegation you are trying is attached to the document, it can cause the ambiguity.

Comment: I see, still I'm having three types of panels, which are scrollable like this and I only want to bind to two types. ... ok. I will try to detect and then check which panel it's from. THANKS!

Comment: ok. Got it to work. Still wondering though, now I'm attaching to 10 elements and filter after detecting scrollstart vs. attaching to 2 elements right away.

Comment: @frequent, I dont understand what you mean.